# Cocos3d and pod files on CocosBuilder or SpriteBuilder

Tags: ios, cocos3d, spritebuilder

In an iOS game. I'm using POD files in cocos3d to load some 3D animations. It is possible to add those animations in SpriteBuilder (or previous CocosBuilder) and load it in the game.

If not what is the best possible alternative.

Comment: SpriteBuilder has no 3D / cocos3d support.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, **cocos3d** requires *cocos2d 2.1*, and does not yet work with *cocos2d 3.0*.

For similar reasons, SpriteBuilder does not yet support **cocos3d** components.

Development is underway to rectify all of this, and should be out in the near future, but at this point, I can't give you a timeline.

Comment: What about using CocosBuilder with cocos2d 2.1? will that support cocos3d

Comment: Unlikely. CocosBuilder was never intended for use with cocos3d.